# DSGVO - Does Python send data to external servers?

Tags: python, security, pdfminer

I work in an industry where I have to make sure that no data is sent. I would like to use Python to read and process PDF files. Do I need to worry about European data protection regulations? - Are there any Python packages that send data?

Kind regards
Dennis

Comment: Python libraries have no limitations - they can install a rootkit if they want to. (However, malicious packages on PyPI are removed once detected.) Anyway, a trustworthy PDF processing library will not send data over the internet. This is not legal advice.

Comment: If you need to make sure no data is sent, do it at the networking level, it would be unwise to blindly trust your applications won't send anything.